# Augmented Reality QualComm virtual button

Tags: android, augmented-reality

i m new in android -ndk AR so need some help  i m using Virtaul button sample (from Vuforia).

can i get the virtual touch to physical touch

like if i touch on the red botton on screen then tea pot changes to red

and if touch the blue button tea pot changes to blue tea pot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out at my own 
Need a complex caclution and 
Used the Following Formula to work with it

```
 QCAR::CameraDevice& cameraDevice = QCAR::CameraDevice::getInstance();
        const QCAR::CameraCalibration& cameraCalibration = cameraDevice.getCameraCalibration();
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Tyre//////////////////////////////////////////
        QCAR::Vec2F cameraPoint = QCAR::Tool::projectPoint(cameraCalibration, trackable->getPose(), QCAR::Vec3F( -97.68, -15.93, 0.f ));
        QCAR::Vec2F cameraPoint1 = QCAR::Tool::projectPoint(cameraCalibration, trackable->getPose(), QCAR::Vec3F( -28, -15.93, 0.f ));
        QCAR::Vec2F cameraPoint2 = QCAR::Tool::projectPoint(cameraCalibration, trackable->getPose(), QCAR::Vec3F( -97.68, -50.52, 0.f));
        QCAR::Vec2F cameraPoint3 = QCAR::Tool::projectPoint(cameraCalibration, trackable->getPose(), QCAR::Vec3F( -28.f, -50.52, 0.f));

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////HeadLight////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        QCAR::Vec2F cameraPoint4 = QCAR::Tool::projectPoint(cameraCalibration, trackable->getPose(), QCAR::Vec3F( -52.28, 53, 0.f ));
        QCAR::Vec2F cameraPoint5 = QCAR::Tool::projectPoint(cameraCalibration, trackable->getPose(), QCAR::Vec3F( -21.f, 53.f, 0.f ));
        QCAR::Vec2F cameraPoint6 = QCAR::Tool::projectPoint(cameraCalibration, trackable->getPose(), QCAR::Vec3F( -53.f, -8.f, 0.f));
        QCAR::Vec2F cameraPoint7 = QCAR::Tool::projectPoint(cameraCalibration, trackable->getPose(), QCAR::Vec3F( -21.f, -8.f, 0.f));
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////Indicator//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        QCAR::Vec2F cameraPoint8 = QCAR::Tool::projectPoint(cameraCalibration, trackable->getPose(), QCAR::Vec3F(-4.f, -94.f, 0.f ));
        QCAR::Vec2F cameraPoint9 = QCAR::Tool::projectPoint(cameraCalibration, trackable->getPose(), QCAR::Vec3F( 18, -94, 0.f ));
        QCAR::Vec2F cameraPoint10 = QCAR::Tool::projectPoint(cameraCalibration, trackable->getPose(), QCAR::Vec3F(-4.f, -71.f, 0.f));
        QCAR::Vec2F cameraPoint11 = QCAR::Tool::projectPoint(cameraCalibration, trackable->getPose(), QCAR::Vec3F( 18.f, -71.f, 0.f));

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        QCAR::Vec2F screenPoint=  cameraPointToScreenPoint(cameraPoint);
        QCAR::Vec2F screenPoint1=  cameraPointToScreenPoint(cameraPoint1);
        QCAR::Vec2F screenPoint2=  cameraPointToScreenPoint(cameraPoint2);
        QCAR::Vec2F screenPoint3=  cameraPointToScreenPoint(cameraPoint3);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        QCAR::Vec2F screenPoint4=  cameraPointToScreenPoint(cameraPoint4);
        QCAR::Vec2F screenPoint5=  cameraPointToScreenPoint(cameraPoint5);
        QCAR::Vec2F screenPoint6=  cameraPointToScreenPoint(cameraPoint6);
        QCAR::Vec2F screenPoint7=  cameraPointToScreenPoint(cameraPoint7);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        QCAR::Vec2F screenPoint8=  cameraPointToScreenPoint(cameraPoint8);
        QCAR::Vec2F screenPoint9=  cameraPointToScreenPoint(cameraPoint9);
        QCAR::Vec2F screenPoint10=  cameraPointToScreenPoint(cameraPoint10);
        QCAR::Vec2F screenPoint11=  cameraPointToScreenPoint(cameraPoint11);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        blY_Tyre=screenPoint.data[0];
        blX_Tyre=screenPoint.data[1];
        brY_Tyre=screenPoint1.data[0];
        brX_Tyre=screenPoint1.data[1];
        tlY_Tyre=screenPoint2.data[0];
        tlX_Tyre=screenPoint2.data[1];
        trY_Tyre=screenPoint3.data[0];
        trX_Tyre=screenPoint3.data[1];
        //////////////////////////////
        blY_Lite=screenPoint4.data[0];
        blX_Lite=screenPoint4.data[1];
        brY_Lite=screenPoint5.data[0];
        brX_Lite=screenPoint5.data[1];
        tlY_Lite=screenPoint6.data[0];
        tlX_Lite=screenPoint6.data[1];
        trY_Lite=screenPoint7.data[0];
        trX_Lite=screenPoint7.data[1];
        //////////////////////////////
        blY_Miror=screenPoint8.data[0];
        blX_Miror=screenPoint8.data[1];
        brY_Miror=screenPoint9.data[0];
        brX_Miror=screenPoint9.data[1];
        tlY_Miror=screenPoint10.data[0];
        tlX_Miror=screenPoint10.data[1];
        trY_Miror=screenPoint11.data[0];
        trX_Miror=screenPoint11.data[1];
```